# Specifing the color for webGL cube in fragment shader

Tags: webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to draw a single colour cube in WebGL and I want to specify the color with in the fragment shader. I know that I can do that when I drawing a square. To eloborate my question can I avoid using the color buffer in the way that it is mention in this tutorial.

["MDN WebGl Tutorial"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=WebGL/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL)

Comment: Try these tutorials? http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really "want to specify the color within the fragment shader", this is your fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
}
```

This would give you green (values in the `vec4()` are r, g, b, a). Of course, in this case you can eliminate all the color stuff under the heading "Define the vertices' colors" in the tutorial.